# Is there a symbol/ way to mathematically indicate an answer?

Tags: convention

I know this is going to sound rather contrived, but I was wondering if there was a symbol to indicate a solution to a problem. I'm a student studying engineering and constantly shift between notations and otherwise, however my conventional underlining is inconsistent and it's grown a little annoying.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: I occasionally use the "therefore" symbol ($\therefore$) when applicable, but this is sometimes looked down upon in engineering.

Answer (score 1):

I usually put the solution in a "box".

Comment: I run into the same inconsistencies with a box as far as the shape is concerned.